# RDLC report Line chart

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer, linechart

when two series intersect, the lines are not getting plotted. In the below the red marked data points belong to one series but since a data point from "Actual rating" series is intersecting the line is not plotted. similarly, the green marked data points belong to "Rating" series. But since a data point from Actual rating is intersecting the line is not plotted. How to solve this?
[image: line chart]